# How do you get the value of a property in the view model of a Vue 3 component?

Tags: vue.js, model, components

I am trying to print the value of a the counter in my "button" control in the DIV element with ID "r1".  However, all that prints is "{{ b1Counter.count }}".

I am using Vue 3 with plain JavaScript.  There are no modules or typescript.  There are two files.

File: button.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Counter</title>
    <script src="/js2/vue-global-min-3.3.4.js"></script>
    <script src="button.js"></script>

    <script>
        var vm = null;
        var b1Counter = null;

        initButton (vmCallbackButton);
    
        function vmCallbackButton (viewModel)
        {
            vm = viewModel;
            b1Counter = vm.$refs.b1;
        }
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Here are many child components!</h1>
    <div id="app">
        <button-counter id="b1" ref="b1"></button-counter>
        <button-counter id="b2"></button-counter>
        <button-counter id="b3"></button-counter>
    </div>
    <div id="r1">{{ b1Counter.count }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

File: button.js

```
var initButton = function (vmCallback)
{
    const ButtonCounter =
    {
        props: ['count'],
        emits: ['update:count'],
        template: `
            <button @click="count++">
                You clicked me {{ count }} times.
            </button>
        `,
        setup()
        {
            const count = Vue.ref (0);

            return { count };
        },
    };



    var vm;

    function registerTag ()
    {
        const app = Vue.createApp ({});
        app.component ('button-counter', ButtonCounter);

        vm = app.mount ('#app');
        vmCallback (vm);
    }



    document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", registerTag);
}
```

I tried injecting the view-model as well, but could not get that working.

Comment: Your vue instance mounts to `<div id="app">` but `<div id="r1">` is outside of that.  Vue is not able to affect elements outside of where it's been mounted.

Comment: Thanks.  That was definitely a problem, but evidently not the only one.  I get a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')" error once that was fixed.  I think I need to inject the view-model, but my attempt to do that has not worked.  I keep getting the undefined error.